# reactjs input select options cannot be added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

Hi I am trying to fetch a list of options from backend and then map them to a list of options and added to a list but failed. Can anybody please advise?

Parent component:

```
fetch(urlMakerNames)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    var array = JSON.parse(responseJson.marker_names);
    var options = array.map((opt, index) => {
        console.log('opt = ' + opt + ', index = ' + index);
        return '<option key="' + index + '" value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';
    });

    console.log('BEFORE options = ' + options + ', markerNames = ' + this.state.markerNames);

    this.setState({
        markerNames: options
    });

    console.log('AFTER options = ' + options + ', markerNames = ' + this.state.markerNames);

}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("MarkerForm error = " + error);
});
```

Child component:

```
console.log('this.props.markerNames = ' + this.props.markerNames);
<FormGroup>
    <Input type="select" name="markerName" onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} disabled={this.props.isViewMode} required>
        <option key="12345" value="TEST">TEST</option>
        {this.props.markerNames}
    </Input>
</FormGroup>
```

Log shows:

```
opt = zzz, index = 0
BEFORE options = <option key="0" value="zzz">zzz</option>, markerNames = 
this.props.markerNames = <option key="0" value="zzz">zzz</option>
AFTER options = <option key="0" value="zzz">zzz</option>, markerNames = <option key="0" value="zzz">zzz</option>
```

As can be seen from log, markerNames are passed into child component in correct format which matches `<option key="12345" value="TEST">TEST</option>` but only TEST option can be seen in the input select element but zzz is gone.

Comment: FormGroup?is part of any lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the array, you do not need to create the elements manually. Use your state as the source for your JSX elements by mapping over the array itself in your render function.

Try this instead:

```
fetch(urlMakerNames)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    var array = JSON.parse(responseJson.marker_names);

    this.setState({
        markerNames: array
    });

}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("MarkerForm error = " + error);
});



    <FormGroup>
        <Input type="select" name="markerName" onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} disabled={this.props.isViewMode} required>
            {this.props.markerNames.map((option, inx)=>{
              return <option key={inx} value={option}>{option}</option>;
            })}
        </Input>
    </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string here instead of a react component

```
return '<option key="' + index + '" value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';
```

Try

```
return <option key={index} value={opt}>{opt}</option>;
```

this will return the react component that will render inside your Input jsx.